# Android studio start project without emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio

@English isn't my first language.
So many questions..
Can I launch my project without emulator on android studio? Something like in libgdx? 
Or how I can change emulator? (need low requirements)

Comment: could use real android device such as a phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up your phone in order to display the app you are developing withoup needing the android emulator itself. You must enlable developer options and maybe install some drivers. Check this links:

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options?hl=en-419

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device

When everytihing is done you should be able to run the app in your phone

Comment: Thank's. I read about this. Are there any restrictions? I try, but android studio didn't see my phone..
Android version 4.2.1

Comment: In the Setting of yout phone you must enlable usb debuging and when the phone is conected to the pc first time you should see a message to accept the connection when android studio is open in order to recognice your phone. It should work. Maybe not the app depending on the target API of the app and your decive Android version, but it Android studio should see your phone. I recommend you to follow this free course: https://eu.udacity.com/course/how-to-install-android-studio--ud808 The last two videos of the course show how to set up the phone and a emulator. Hope it helps

Comment: Try another phone. All work fine. I think that's some think with my phone)
Thanks all for help.